# 2d float** or double** array runtime

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I have to create an array of array named m2DArray. It has 2 rows and 5 cols i;e a size of [2][5].

The array can be `float**` or `double**` which is known to me only at runtime.

Since I do not know the type at compile time, I initialize it in my header files as

```
void **m2DArray;
```

Then I create a template function:

```
template <typename SampleType>
void MyClass::initiliaze2DArray(SampleType** m2DArrayTyped)
{
    m2DArray = new SampleType* [2]; //2 rows
    int32 sizeOfOneCol =  5 * sizeof(SampleType); // 5 cols
    for (int32 row = 0; row < 2; row++)
    {
        m2DArray[row] = new  SampleType [sizeOfOneColumn];
    memset(m2DArray[row], 0, sizeOfOneCol);
    }
}
```

Then at runtime I decide between float** or double** based on some logic in the class and accordingly try to initalize the 2d array.

```
if (somelogictellsfloat){
   float **mArrayFloat;
   initiliaze2DArray(mArrayFloat);
} 
else {
   double **mArrayDouble;
   initiliaze2DArray(mArrayDouble);
}
```

However, when trying to initialize this 2d array, I am not able to convert the void** to either float** or double** in my template function.

I get the following error:

> error: invalid conversion from ‘double**’ to ‘void**’ in line m2DArray = new SampleType* [2];

**My Question:**

How do I cast **m2DArray from void ** to float ** or double ** ? Or is there a better way to create this 2d array at runtime.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a wrapper class, like `template<typename SampleType> class Array2D`? If the object has to exist from the beginning, create some interface `Array2DBase` from which the template class inherits and create a pointer to that.

Comment: @Aziuth  Thanks, I cannot use class template as it is part of a bigger code base and I really don't have that independence to modify the class to use a template.

Comment: And also, is `m2DArray`a global variable? If so, try to rewrite it, is evil anyway. Edit: ah okay, other code you have to use, got it.

Comment: m2DArray is a class member attribute.

Comment: A `union` comes into my mind or (better) a [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) (but the latter has been introduced with C++17).

Comment: @bhaskarc `if (typeisFloat) { RunMyApp<float>(argc, argv); } else {RunMyApp<double>(argc, argv); }` -- Have you considered that?  RunMyApp is a template function that is basically your application.  If you did that, the `void**` is not necessary.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<void**>` will make it compile but it's probably not wise. why do you assign to `m2DArray` twice?

Comment: @AlanBirtles - yes there should be only one assignment there. I tried reinterpret_cast and it does compile but gives all nasty errors in runtime.

Comment: @bhaskarc Anything involving a double indirection is going to be trouble.  Add to that, the double indirection is a `void **`.  Your best bet is to figure out the type, create the 2D array of that type, breathe a sigh of relief your code got that far, then work with that type, not `void **`.  To me, a lot of your code could be templated, with concrete function not relying on `void **` placed in a class or in a namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some misunderstandings here. Most important: `void**` is NOT a generic pointer. The only generic pointer is `void*`. So, your type `void**` can hold the address of a generic `void*`. This you need to understand.

So, regardless, how many dimensions your array would have, you could assign it to a `void*`. And later, it is your responsibility to cast it to your needed type. See:

```
    // Create a 5 dimensional array
    char***** dimension5 = static_cast<char*****>( malloc(200));    
    // Assign it to a generic pointer
    void* generic = dimension5;                                     
    // Get the address of the generic pointer
    void** addressOfGeneric = &generic;
    // Now dereference the address of the generic pointer to get back the generic pointer 
    // and cast it to our original type
    char***** dimension5Later = static_cast<char*****>(*addressOfGeneric);
    // Do something with the array
    dimension5Later[0][0][0][0][0] = 'H';
```

But, of course we would never do that. In C++ we should never use raw pointers for owned memory. We should try to avoid raw pointers at all and work with smart pointers. We must not use `malloc` and we should not even use `new` and instead some `make_unique`-function.

I wonder, if you need that at all. Because you should use `std::vector` instead.

Please see the following:

```
    // The dimension of our 2d vector
    constexpr size_t NumberOfRows = 2U;
    constexpr size_t NumberOfColumns = 5U;
    bool somelogictellsfloat{ true };

    // Depending on what to create
    if (somelogictellsfloat) {

        // Create and initialize a 2d vector for floats
        std::vector<std::vector<float>> mArrayFloat(NumberOfRows, std::vector<float>(NumberOfColumns, 0.0));
    }
    else {
        // Create and initialize a 2d vector for doubles
        std::vector<std::vector<double>> mArrayDouble(NumberOfRows, std::vector<double>(NumberOfColumns, 0.0));
    }
```

But what you really want, is to use the abstract factory pattern. If you do not know, the please read about this.

By the way. I made for your original code a minimum reproducable example. This you should always do in questions on SO.

I fixed some bugs and made it compilable. But please do not use

```
#include <cstring>
#include < cstdlib >
#include <vector>

struct MyClass {

    void** m2DArray;   // Address of a generic pointer
    void* md;
    float** mArrayFloat;
    double** mArrayDouble;
    using int32 = int;

    template <typename SampleType>
    void initiliaze2DArray(SampleType** m2DArrayTyped)
    {
        m2DArrayTyped = new SampleType * [2]; //2 rows
        int32 sizeOfOneCol = 5 * sizeof(SampleType); // 5 cols
        for (int32 row = 0; row < 2; row++)
        {
            m2DArrayTyped[row] = new  SampleType[5];
            memset(m2DArrayTyped[row], 0, sizeOfOneCol);
        }
        md = m2DArrayTyped; // md is now a generic pointer 
        m2DArray = &md;     // and m2DArray is the address of that generic pointer
    }
    // Test function
    void test(bool doFloatAndNotDouble) {
        if (doFloatAndNotDouble) {
            initiliaze2DArray(mArrayFloat);
        }
        else {
            initiliaze2DArray(mArrayDouble);
        }
    }
};
// Driver code
int main() {

    MyClass mc{};
    mc.test(true);
    mc.test(false);
    return 0;
}
```